# jquery hover image animate image in size and pan left

Tags: jquery

I have a grid of images and I'm trying to work out how I can hover over one image have it zoom in but as the image zooms on the actual visible area is the same so when it's done zooming in a animate is triggered to animate the image left.

this currently what I'm trying. I think I need to change my css so the image stays within a confined viewable area

my JS

```
$('.grid img').on({
mouseenter: function(){
    $(this).animate({width: '406px', height: '253px'}, 800, function(){
        $(this).animate({right: '50px'},1000);
         });
       },
mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).animate({ right: '0px', width: '339px', height: '211px'}, 800);
   }
});
```

mu css

```
body{background:url(bg.jpg);}

ul.grid {
 list-style: none;
  top: 0;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
  width: 1200px; 
  }

.grid li span {   
  background:url(mag.png);
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;   
  top:2px;
  right: 2px;
  position:absolute;   
 }

.grid li a:hover img {
 -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opactiy .3s ease-in;
 -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
 -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
 transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
 opacity: 1;
 }

.grid:hover li {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opactiy .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  opacity: 0.3;
 }

.grid li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 40px 75px 0px;
 display:inline;
 position:relative;
  }

.grid li img {
  margin: 0;
  width: 339px;
  height: 211px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

.grid:hover li:hover {opacity: 1;}
.grid img::selection { background-color: transparent; }

#hidden{
 position:absolute;
 width: 1300px;
 height:670px;
 top:0px;
 z-index:-1;
 }

.title{
 font-size: 100%;
 top: -40px;
 color: white;
 left: 0%;
 position: absolute;    
 z-index: 1;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DtG6f/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery at all, it'd be easiest to just use CSS3 transitions like you have on the opacity. [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/DtG6f/4/)

Here is the relevant updated CSS

```
.grid li a:hover img {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.15);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.15); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.grid:hover li {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.grid li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 40px 75px 0px;
  display:inline;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  opacity:1;
}

.grid li img {
  margin: 0;
  width: 339px;
  height: 211px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the image when hovered and blowing up to do more of a zooming in effect, so the actual visible width and height are the same.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Do you mean have all other images get smaller instead?

Comment: sorry it's hard to explain. you mouse hover over and image and it zooms in on the image like what a magnifying glass would do.

Comment: You can simulate a magnifying glass, but that's a very complex process. See [here](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3) or [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=css3+magnifying+effect&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS527US527&oq=css3+magnifying+effect&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l2j69i62l2.4616j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I don't think you want something that complex